# How customize column width in column series?

Tags: wpf, xaml, livecharts

I would like to know if is possible to customize the column width of a bar graph.

Regards

Franco

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer, yes, see [this](http://lvcharts.net/App/documentation/beta/LiveCharts-Wpf-ColumnSeries), you should be able to customize everything in Live-Charts, by default `MaxColumnWidth` property is 35px, this means the bar will be capped at 35 px, no matter if there is more available space, if you change this property your bars will grow, `mySeries.MaxColumnWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;`

Playing with the column properties you can practically achieve any effect:

[image]

But it is a bit more complicated than that, bars will only have a greater width if there is enough space to grow, the width of any bar (ColumnSeries, RowSeries, StackedRow and StackedColumn), do always have a width of 1 chart unit, this because as you can notice the chart scales no matter what values you give to it, the next diagram explains a bit how it works:

[image]

For a bar series, the available space of a bar changes according to the number of visible bars:

[image]

You can only customize the max value, never the minimum dimension, in both previous cases the column width was capped by the `MaxColumnWidth` property, but notice when there are many bars, column's width needs to be less than 35px to be displayed correctly.

[image]